# How to add select/deselect all layers button on the leaflet webmap created via qgis2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, javascript, qgis2web

I have a leaflet web map created via qgis2web plugin using qgis software. There is no option in plugin window to generate select/deselect button for the map layer. Now I want to add that button on the map, but I don't know which code part and where I should add it.

Answer (score 3):

Understanding you want a button for all on, and a button for all off. Not using the Leaflet Layers control.

I've put two buttons outside my map div,

```
<input type="button" value="Turn on Layers" onclick="turnLayerOn()" />
<input type="button" value="Turn off Layers" onclick="turnLayerOff()" />
```

and using a layerList these two functions turn on or off the layers in the list.

```
////////////////    Turns Layers on/off by button
    var layerList = [ NLTeam, ALTeam ]  // no quotes as layers are objects

    function turnLayerOn(){ 
        for (i = 0; i < layerList.length; i++) { 

            if(!map.hasLayer(layerList[i])) {  //note the ! for off.
                map.addLayer(layerList[i]);
            }
        }

    }
    function turnLayerOff(){ 
        for (i = 0; i < layerList.length; i++) { 

            if(map.hasLayer(layerList[i])) {  
                map.removeLayer(layerList[i]);
            }
        }

    }
/////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an html button which has an on click function. i.e.

```
<input type="button" value="Turn on Layer" onclick="turnLayerOn()" />
```

Now define a function that turns it on:

```
function turnLayerOn(){ 
   map.addLayer(waterLayer);
}
```

Or have a turn off button: which would map.removeLayer(waterLayer);

Another option is to determine if it's added then remove or if not added, then add it, make a function for this and call it on the button click.

```
if(map.hasLayer(waterLayer)) {  //layer added is true
     map.removeLayer(waterLayer);
}else{
     map.addLayer(waterLayer)
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a control to toggle *all* layers.

Comment: He needs a list of layers  Then for i in layerList use the map.hasLayer(i) and either addLayer or removeLayer based on it's current status.

Comment: I just want to turn on/off all layers checking the box or clicking on the button.